# glDrawElements causing access violation exception

Tags: opengl

So I have recently rewritten the rendering portion of my hobby OpenGL graphics engine and I can't seem to figure out why I am getting an access violation exception being thrown on glDrawElements.

From what I have researched already, it is usually due to a mis-configured VAO but from what I can see, everything seems fine.

Below is an order of OpenGL calls I am making before getting the error. Unfortunately I can't log the values of each parameter but if anyone can notice an error in the order please let me know.

Note that I am running OpenGL 4.1 on a 1080 Nvidia graphics card and the drivers are up to date.

```
glCreateShaderProgramv(GetShaderType(_desc.ShaderType), 1, &ptr)
glGetProgramiv(_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength)
glGetProgramiv(_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus)
glCreateShaderProgramv(GetShaderType(_desc.ShaderType), 1, &ptr)
glGetProgramiv(_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength)
glGetProgramiv(_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus)
glGenBuffers(1, &_id)
glBindBuffer(target, _id)
glBufferData(target, _desc.ByteCount, 0, GetBufferUsage(_desc.BufferUsage))
glBindBuffer(target, _id)
glMapBufferRange(target, byteOffset, byteCount, access)
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL)
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_POINT)
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE)
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)
glScissor(0, 0, _desc.RenderWidth, _desc.RenderHeight)
glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP)
glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT, GetStencilOp(stencilOperationDesc.FailOp), GetStencilOp(stencilOperationDesc.ZFailOp), GetStencilOp(stencilOperationDesc.PassOp))
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT, GetStencilOp(stencilOperationDesc.FailOp, true), GetStencilOp(stencilOperationDesc.ZFailOp, true), GetStencilOp(stencilOperationDesc.PassOp, true))
glStencilFuncSeparate(GL_FRONT, GetCompareFunc(comparisonFunc), _stencilRefValue, readMask)
glStencilFuncSeparate(GL_BACK, GetCompareFunc(comparisonFunc), _stencilRefValue, readMask)
glStencilMask(writeMask)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)
glDepthFunc(GetCompareFunc(depthFunc))
glGenBuffers(1, &_id)
glBindBuffer(target, _id)
glBufferData(target, _desc.ByteCount, 0, GetBufferUsage(_desc.BufferUsage))
glBindBuffer(target, _id)
glMapBufferRange(target, byteOffset, byteCount, access)
glGenBuffers(1, &_id)
glBindBuffer(target, _id)
glBufferData(target, _desc.ByteCount, 0, GetBufferUsage(_desc.BufferUsage))
glBindBuffer(target, _id)
glMapBufferRange(target, byteOffset, byteCount, access)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, glIndexBuffer->GetId())
glGenProgramPipelines(1, &_id)
glUseProgramStages(_id, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, desc.VertexShaderId)
glUseProgramStages(_id, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, desc.PixelShaderId)
glUseProgramStages(_id, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT, desc.GeometryShaderId)
glUseProgramStages(_id, GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER_BIT, desc.HullShaderId)
glUseProgramStages(_id, GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER_BIT, desc.DomainShaderId)
glBindProgramPipeline(shaderPipeline->GetId())
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao)
glBindVertexArray(vao)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, boundBuffers[inputSlot]->GetId())
glVertexAttribPointer(inputSlot, compSize, compType, GL_FALSE, stride, reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(offset))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(inputSlot)
glBindVertexArray(0)
glBindVertexArray(vao->GetId())
```

Comment: Using some nullptr with glBufferData() looks very suspicious )

Comment: Yep, when you pass nullptr as data to `glBufferData`, content of the buffer is undefined. From what you've included, it seems that you aren't updating index buffer, so  indices are undefined.

Comment: Looks like not all my OpenGL calls are getting logged. Let me fix that. But I am setting the data using glMapBufferRange.

Comment: You could try using ApiTrace and share the trace file.

Comment: I have updated the calls. I tried using ApiTrace but no luck - gave errors.

Comment: It seems you are binding the index buffer only before the VAO is bound. If you want it to be attached to the VAO, you have to bind it while the VAO is bound. The log does btw not really make sense. Why is there a completely different VAO bound at the end? which VAO is finally used in the rendering? Where is the draw call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was passing an invalid size when creating a VBO.